# How to create a loss function which changes over epoch in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I would like to create a custom loss function that has a weight term that's updated based on what epoch I'm in.

For example:
Let's say I have a loss function which has a `beta` weight, where beta increases over the first 20 epochs...

```
def custom_loss(x, x_pred): 
    loss1 = objectives.binary_crossentropy(x, x_pred)
    loss2 = objectives.mse(x, x_pred)
    return (beta*current_epoch/20) * loss1 + loss2
```

How could I implement something like this into a keras loss function?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at their documentation they mention that you can use theano/Tf symbolic functions that return a scalar for each data point.
So you could do something like this

```
loss = tf.contrib.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(x, x_pred) * 
       (beta * current_epoch / 20 ) +  
       tf.contrib.losses.mean_squared_error
```

You would have to pass x and x_pred as x and x_pred as tf.placeholders
I think for model creation you could use keras but then again you would have to run the computational graph with sess.run()

References:
https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html#using-keras-models-with-tensorflow