# How to create a loss function parameter that is dependent on epoch number in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I have a custom loss function with a hyperparameter `alpha` that I want to change every 20 epochs over training. The loss function is something like:

```
def custom_loss(x, x_pred): 
    loss1 = binary_crossentropy(x, x_pred)
    loss2 = (x, x_pred)
    return (alpha)* loss1 + (1-alpha)*loss2
```

From my research, creating a custom callback is the way to go. I have looked at the solution for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995711/keras-epoch-dependant-loss-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055225/how-to-create-a-loss-function-which-changes-over-epoch-in-keras) but the solutions do not implement the callback solution which is what I want to accomplish.

I've attempted to create a custom callback by altering the `LearningRateScheduler` callback from the [keras repo](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L633)

```
class changeAlpha(Callback):
    def __init__(self, alpha):
        super(changeAlpha, self).__init__()
        self.alpha = alpha 

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if epoch%20 == 0:   
             K.set_value(self.alpha, K.get_value(self.alpha) * epoch**0.95)
             print("Setting alpha to =", str(alpha))
```

However, I am not certain the alpha value actually corresponds to the alpha value in my loss function. In any case, when I put the `changeAlpha` callback in the `model.fit` method, I receive an `attribute error`.

Can someone help me edit the callback such that it alters my `alpha` parameter after a certain number of epochs?

Answer (score 4):

I understood your idea. I think that the problem is that the alpha in the loss function is not referred to the member of changeAlpha class. You can try like this:

```
instance = changeAlpha()
def custom_loss(x, x_pred): 
    loss1 = binary_crossentropy(x, x_pred)
    loss2 = (x, x_pred)
    return (instance.alpha*)* loss1 + (1-instance.alpha)*loss2
```

Or, you can make the alpha as the class variable not the install variable, and then change the loss function as below:

```
def custom_loss(x, x_pred): 
    loss1 = binary_crossentropy(x, x_pred)
    loss2 = (x, x_pred)
    return (changeAlpha.alpha*)* loss1 + (1-changeAlpha.alpha)*loss2
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: It seems to me that this only works if eager execution is enabled, which can make it quite slow.